# What is memelemum?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Here's a ... text? poem? dictionary? list? Something...

> e m me mum mele mem mume mumm melee melem meme memum mumele

Oh! Errors. Fixed:

> e m me mum mele mem mume mumum melele melem meme memum mumele

Given the above, what does 'memelemum' signify, and why that is?

(Okay, I can see that a robot might question whether this "completely describes the problem - and is written using proper grammar". I hereby assure said bot that that is indeed the case.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `memelemum` signifies

> the number 83

because

> this is lightly disguised binary where `e` is 0 and `m` is 1; for euphony you insert `l` between instances of `e` and `u` between instances of `m`, except that for reasons I don't quite understand you write `mumm` instead of `mumum`. (Perhaps there's a rule that collapses strings of `um`s or something.)

so

> `memelemum` = `memeemm` = `1010011` = 83.

Comment: I guess because ROT13(Jr nqq y be h ng zbfg bapr, naq cvpx gur yrsgzbfg cnve? r.t. zzrrrrzz jvyy or zhzryrrrzz?)

Comment: Certainly possible. I don't think we have enough information here to deduce the exact rules with any confidence.

Comment: At least there is "melee" also, but yeah $2$ instances are maybe not enough..

Comment: Rot13(Gurer vf h qvivqvat gur svefg bs rirel zz cnve naq y qvivqvat gur svefg bs rirel rr cnve. Ubjrire gung ovanel ahzore vf bayl qrpvzny rvtugl guerr).

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops, yes, I erred. Good catch.

Comment: I agree that it would have been good to add some more elements to the problem's list to verify that rule.

Comment: It doesn't really matter since the specific goal was to interpret a MLUE string rather than to generate one.

Comment: I agree with your answer but  your "because" isn't the reason why you think it should be the answer.  For instance, why wouldn't you just guess that lower case ell means 2?  In fact, the "because" is that this explanation explains why the "words" in the problem are in this exact order, and it predicts what the next one will be.

Comment: The explanation for the 'mumm' is rather mundane:it's a mistake on my part.